# Raspberry Pi talking together using USB

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, embedded, usb, pyusb

I want to develop a PyUSB program which listens to data from USB. However, I wish to expand the application to talk another Raspberry Pi through USB port. I wonder is it possible?

Comment: This might lead to some answers.. [Raspberry to Arduino](http://blog.oscarliang.net/connect-raspberry-pi-and-arduino-usb-cable/)

Answer (score 0):

USB is a master/slave protocol where a USB *device* is connected to a USB *host*.  You cannot directly connect a USB host to a USB host.  The RPi is a USB host.

What is possible however is to use two USB devices that connect via some other interface such as UART and each connect to a different host.  For example you could use two FTDI USB/Serial bridge devices back-to-back:

```
                    __________      ________
                    |     Tx |______|Rx     |
USB Host A ---------|     Rx |______|Tx     |---------USB Host B
                    |________|      |_______|
                      FT323R         FT323R
```

As such it is largely a hardware problem not a software problem.  The data rate will be limited by the capability of the USB/Serial device - 3MBaud for the FT232.  Note that a real implementation you would also connect the RTS/CTS flow control pins, but there is a limit to my ASCII diagramming patience!

A probably better solution is to use a commercially available [USB bridge cable](http://Rather%20the%20building%20such%20a%20cable,%20commercially%20available%20USD%20bridge%20cables%20are%20available); these use the same principle as serial bridge solution described above, but instead of emulating a COM/TTY port, emulate an network interface and can run at full USB speed.  You could of course implement such a cable but I doubt it would be cost effective even compared with solution I suggested above. I do not know whether suitable drivers for USB network adapters exist for RPi however.

Given that RPi has Ethernet, that would be a far simpler method of board to board communication and is not limited to point-to-point, but can access an entire network, and there will be no USB driver issues to tackle.

Comment: With a little software configuration to quiet console messages, one could also use some combinations of the pi's hardware UARTs, either wired crossover to each other, or one crossed over to a USB-logic serial converter hanging off the other.  There is the theoretical (though as far as I've heard unrealized in software) possibility to run the single "bare" USB port on a model A or zero in device mode, something the intervening hub chip on the B and similar blocks.

Comment: @ChrisStratton : As I recall one of the available UARTs is somewhat limited in capability which may be an issue.  In the end there are better solutions in any case such as a USB bridge cable (also known as an USB network cable or Easy Transfer cable) about which I have added a note, and the Ethernet solution is a no-brainer in my opinion.  An interesting question, but not really one for SO but perhaps http://electronics.stackexchange.com/.  However it is for others to vote to close; it would be inconsistent to vote to close a question I bothered to answer.